# Unable to Execute code from Android Docs

Tags: android, networking

//This is the class with constructor having argument(DownloadCallback)

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask {

```
private DownloadCallback<String> mCallback;

DownloadTask(DownloadCallback<String> callback) {
    setCallback(callback);
}

void setCallback(DownloadCallback<String> callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
}
```

// creating object of Download

```
* Start non-blocking execution of DownloadTask.
 */
public void startDownload() {
    cancelDownload();
    mDownloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    mDownloadTask.execute(mUrlString);
}
```

As we can see the creation of new Object requires argument, but this code which was in google Android Documentations doesnt provide any. I am stuck this one error
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: The code is working as intended. The AsyncTask is asking for a `String`, will update with an `Integer`, and will return a `DownloadTask.Result`.

Comment: Also, any object in Java has an empty constructor. Even when another constructor is made, it will still have that empty constructor.

Comment: But then i am getting error, as attempt to invoke on null object reference

Comment: show your work, I can't help you much with just assumptions.

Comment: can i give github link?

Comment: mCallback variable is remaining null when i try to debug